# If $H \trianglelefteq G$ and $H \subseteq G' \leq G$ then $(G' \trianglelefteq G) \Leftrightarrow (G'/H \trianglelefteq G/H)$

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

I tried to prove the statement in both directions at once, as a chain of equivalent statements:

> 1. $G' \trianglelefteq G$.
> 2. $xG'x^{-1} = G'$ for all $x \in G$.
> 3. $\{xyx^{-1} \mid y \in G'\} = \{y \mid y \in G'\}$ for all $x \in G$.
> 4. $\{xyx^{-1}H \mid y \in G'\} = \{yH \mid y \in G'\}$ for all $x \in G$.
> 5. $\{xHyHx^{-1}H \mid y \in G'\} = \{yH \mid y \in G'\}$ for all $x \in G$.
> 6. $(xH)(G'/H)(x^{-1}H) = G'/H$ for all $xH \in G/H$.
> 7. $G'/H \trianglelefteq G/H$.

Here, 1 ⇔ 2 ⇔ 3 by definition, 3 ⇒ 4 by applying $\alpha \mapsto \alpha H$ to everything in the set, 4 ⇔ 5 by normality of $H$ in $G$ (we can twiddle the cosets around: $xHyHx^{-1}H=xyx^{-1}HHH=xyx^{-1}H$), and 5 ⇔ 6 ⇔ 7 by definition.

However, I’m not sure how to motivate that 4 ⇒ 3, to finish the proof. I haven't yet used the condition that $H \subseteq G'$, so it’s probably relevant. But I see no way to use it. Can I get a hint?

Comment: The notation $G^{\prime}$ has a very specific meaning is group theory, so it is a good idea to avoid it in general...no reason you should have known this though :-)

Comment: I see! The notation is my lecturer’s; we haven’t yet assigned any special meaning to $G'$ in class. I’ll keep it in mind for the future.

Comment: Indeed. It's the [commutator subgroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_subgroup) and that's a group one can meet when learning group theory.

Comment: @user1729 Just for the record, I disagree with that. The notation $G'$ is far too useful to be reserved for the derived group.

Comment: @DerekHolt I think it is always nice to be aware of these things though. I wrote my comment because I was initially confused :-)

Comment: While your approach is correct, it is conceptually helpful to think of this statement in terms of the natural homomorphism $G \to G/H$.  Indeed, the statement is a part of the Correspondence Theorem.  For any element or subset $A$ of $G$ let $\bar{A}$ denote its image in $G/H$.  You are to prove that for all $x \in G$ and $y \in Y$, $x^{-1} Y x = Y$ if and only if $\bar{x}^{-1} \bar{Y} \bar{x} = \bar{Y}$, where $H \leq Y \leq G$ are the given groups.  The property of being a homomorphism (and that it's surjective) is exactly what you need for this to be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: 4 means that every $xyx^{-1}H$, where $x\in G$ and $y\in G'$, there exists $y'\in G'$ such that $xyx^{-1}H=y'H$. But what you need is $xyx^{-1}$, not the hole coset of $H$. Let $e$ denote the identity element of $G$. Of course $e\in H$. So $xyx^{-1}=xyx^{-1}e\in xyx^{-1}H=y'H$. Indeed you'll need the assumption $H\subseteq G'$ here.

P.S: I find proofs of equivalences by chain of equivalences splendid!

Comment: I completed the proof nicely! Thank you. ^^

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

I will write $L$ instead of $G'$.
We know that

$$H \trianglelefteq G$$
$$H \le L \le G$$
$$xLx^{-1}H = LH$$

and we need to prove

$$xLx^{-1} = L$$

Notice that $LH = L$ and that $$xLx^{-1}H = xL(x^{-1}Hx)x^{-1} = xLHx^{-1} = xLx^{-1}$$

Thus $xLx^{-1} = xLx^{-1}H = LH = L$.

Comment: Why $LH = L$? I am confused...

Comment: @JoshuaOrtiz Because $H$ is a subgroup of $L$. $LH$ denotes the pointwise product, $LH = \{xy : x \in L, y \in H\}$.

Comment: OOOHHHHHH.... Makes sense now hahaha. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assert indirectly that statement 3 is not true. Then $∃y ∈ G', ∃x ∈ G$ such that $xyx^{-1} \not\in G'$. (The set on the right hand side will always be contained in the one on the left. Just take $x=e$)

Now consider $G'/H$ as a subgroup of $G/H$. Assert there exists a $z ∈ G'$ such that the left cosets $xyx^{-1}H = zH$ coincide. This is equivalent to $xyx^{-1}z^{-1} ∈ H \subseteq G'$. Now since $z ∈ G'$, $xyx^{-1} ∈ G'$, as well. A contradiction.